# How to deal with DatePicker in Appium with Robot Framework?

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

I'm trying to select some Date,
[https://postimg.cc/LqF0XDmD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOXoY.png)
but my xpath is not a "DataPicker" it is
"SeekBar" `xpath=//android.widget.SeekBar[@content-desc="1"] xpath=//android.widget.SeekBar[@content-desc="janeiro"] xpath=//android.widget.SeekBar[@content-desc="1996"]`